Unable to Change Camera Encoding to <format>B8G8R8</format> in Gazebo Simulation
I'm using Gazebo Sim Garden with ROS 2 Humble to simulate camera data. While the simulation camera works well with the default rgb8 encoding, I'd like to change the simulated camera encoding to match my real camera's B8G8R8 encoding (BGR). However, setting B8G8R8 doesn't seem to take effect; the camera output remains in the rgb8 format. What could be causing this issue?
$ gazebo --version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
$ ign gazebo --version
ignition version:
Gazebo Sim, version 6.16.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">


  <!-- Gazebo plugins -->
  <gazebo>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!--example camera interface -->
  <gazebo reference="rgb_camera_optical_frame">
    <!-- RGB Camera -->
    <sensor name="left_camera" type="camera">
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <topic>/rgb/image_rect</topic>
      <ignition_frame_id>rgb_camera_optical_frame</ignition_frame_id>
      <camera name="oakd-rgb">
        <horizontal_fov>1.48702</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>400</height>
          <format>B8G8R8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0</mean>
          <stddev>0.07</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

</robot>


isn't the format bgr8?

First:

There is Gazebo Classic, i.e. 'old Gazebo', with executable gazebo. This is the one with version 11.10.2.
Then there is 'new Gazebo'.

Up until version 6 (i.e. 'Fortress'), 'new Gazebo' was called 'Ignition' with executable ign. So above command line $ ign gazebo --version shows that you are running Gazebo Fortress (although you mention Gazebo Garden in your question).
Due to a trademark issue, Ignition was renamed to Gazebo Sim, from version 7 (i.e. 'Garden') on. The executable became gz. I.e. since Garden, you would write $ gz sim --version instead.



Now, wrt. the question:
The SDFormat specs do indeed show B8G8R8 as a valid format specifier.
However, it seems that that format is not included in the code, see this section.
This implies that you should be getting the error message "Unsupported pixel format" in the Gazebo Sim log output.
Given that B8G8R8 seems supported in gz-rendering (see here: there's a type definition and a test case), I assume that it might just be a matter of extending above code section with a corresponding case statement.

thank you for your feedback. That is a good approach.

Were you able to resolve it? If not, I suggest to file an issue in the gz-sensors repository.
